# Nginx is not workingnafter creating aws ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, nginx, amazon-ec2

After I created AWS EC2 instance, which is running Ubuntu, I started ubuntu with Putty. Then I installed Nginx using these commands:
`sudo apt-get udpate` and
`sudo apt-get install nginx`
After this, to check that Nginx was working, I entered the ip address in the browser, but I got `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT` error. Why is Nginx not working? 
I only followed https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04. I don't know why it is not working.

Comment: `sudo ufw allow 'Nginx HTTP'` => `sudo ufw status`. Verify your nginx service running by `sudo systemctl status nginx`

Answer (score 7):

Check you security group that attached to you EC2 instance and add HTTP and HTTPS rules and IP anywhere. After that try agin, hope it will work for you.
[Group Policy setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9nl7.png)

Answer (score 6):

You should go
Security > Security Groups

- Choose the rule active in your instance of EC2, and click edit
- Then you should add rules with the ports (80 and 443) (Http and Https) as the bellow image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHd7n.png)